# md5 и русские буквы

Tags: md5, хеширование

Разные веб-сервисы по генерации md5 хэшей дают разные результаты.

Для примера генерируем `md5('Я')`:

- на *www.md5.cz*

  > feef0975aac3bd15d35f5279ae70d0ba
- на *wb0.ru/strmd5.php*

  > a26785922b3516fe627bab9726c66e43

В чем тут разница?

Comment: Проверьте кодировку файлов. Возможно, один в UTF8, второй в Windows-1251.

Comment: Я догадываюсь, что дело в кодировке. Но мне надо просто узнать хэш от пароля (допустим, пароль "Я") на русской раскладке. Какой из этих вариантов правильный?

Comment: Денис, оба. Всё зависит от кодировки в которой приходит строка с паролем на расчет md5 при его проверке.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Разница в кодировке строки, от которой берётся md5. То, в какой кодировке придёт на вход функции md5 строка, в свою очередь, будет зависеть от кодировки HTML на странице с формой.

Вывод: не пользуйтесь веб-сервисами, пользуйтесь консольной реализацией. Какая кодировка у Вас в консоли - будет завиесть только от Ваших действий.